# Estimating the size of a tree

Tags: algorithm, math, tree, graph

I'd like to estimate the number of leaves in a large tree structure for which I can't visit every node exhaustively. Is this algorithm appropriate? Does it have a name? Also, please pedant if I am using any terms improperly.

```
sum_trials = 0
num_trials = 0
WHILE time_is_not_up
    bits = 0
    ptr = tree.root
    WHILE count(ptr.children) > 0
         bits += log2(count(ptr.children))
         ptr = ptr.children[rand()%count(ptr.children)]
    sum_trials += bits
    num_trials++
estimated_tree_size = 2^(sum_trials/num_trials)
```

Comment: I can't see how this could possibly work on an unbalanced tree of any kind.  It'd make more sense to customize the tree object itself to keep track of this kind of stuff during inserts and removals.

Comment: Think huge, like a tree of all possible checkers games. Not something that would be in memory.

Comment: I understand huge. :)  It seems you could either have a tree that does physically exist (even it its split up) or you have a tree that doesn't actually exist and is being generated from a given node as needed.  In the first case, the tree-genning code needs to keep stats to give you what you want.  The second case, you can't solve for any arbitrary tree structure.  If you've got a special second case -- like checkers game permutations -- there are better methods to use than statistical sampling.

Comment: Here are some more documents I can read: 
Estimating Search Tree Size, Philip Kilby et al
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.5569&rep=rep1&type=pdf
Knuth, D. 1975. Estimating the efficiency of backtrack programs. Mathematics of Computation 29(129):121–136.

Comment: If your estimate is to have meaning as a statistic you also need to compute (or estimate) the variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be possible if you can make some safe assumptions about your tree (such as: is it balanced?) and its usage (is there a safe assumption about how many leaves will be children of the same node?). Better yet would be if you maintain a running tally (counter) everytime you add/remove a leaf node. Then you just access your counter variable in a single operation.

Comment: I cannot assume the tree is balanced. But I can put an upper bound on depth. Does this help? This tree will be huge, for example representing all moves in a perfect information game.

Comment: Hm that might give you a worst-case estimate for number of leaves, but to get closer, you need to know more. Is there a way to know/estimate how many branches actually reach maximum depth?

Comment: I don't know how to estimate how many branches reach maximum depth, but those are actually the only ones I'm interested in counting. I'm going to continue this topic with additional questions.

Answer (score 3):

A theory of estimating tree sizes, fundamental for the analysis of exponential-time
algorithms and for certain areas of heuristics, is in

Handbook of Satisfiability, IOS Press 2009, ISBN 978-1-58603-929-5
(editors Armin Biere, Marijn J.H. Heule, Hans van Maaren and Toby Walsh)
http://www.iospress.nl/book/handbook-of-satisfiability/

namely the chapter 7 "Fundaments of Branching Heuristics" (pages 205-244).
The underlying technical report is
http://www.swan.ac.uk/compsci/research/reports/2008/CSR7-2008.pdf
The chapter is available at
http://www.booksonline.iospress.nl/Content/View.aspx?piid=11712

This theory generalises the approach in the above mentioned paper by Donald Knuth (1975,
Estimating the Efficiency of Backtrack Programs).